# Reuse modal implemented in Django

Tags: javascript, django, modal-dialog

I know this is common to ask but I search for different solutions but couldn't yet find one, Is there any way to reuse the modal? instead of making different modals in each function why not reuse it into just one, is there any way to implement it, especially in Django?
should I transfer it into a javascript file?

**What I've tried is extending the HTML to the main file but it couldn't work**

**modal.html**    templates/modal.html

```
{% block modal_scripts %}
<div class="modal-onboarding modal fade animate__animated" id="onboardImageModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content text-center">
        <div class="modal-header border-0">
        <a class="text-muted close-label" href="javascript:void(0);" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            >Skip Intro</a
        >
        <button
            type="button"
            class="btn-close"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
        ></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body p-0">
        <div class="onboarding-media">
            <div class="mx-2">
            <img
                src="../../assets/img/illustrations/girl-unlock-password-light.png"
                alt="girl-unlock-password-light"
                width="335"
                class="img-fluid"
                data-app-light-img="illustrations/girl-unlock-password-light.png"
                data-app-dark-img="illustrations/girl-unlock-password-dark.png"
            />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="onboarding-content mb-0">
            <h4 class="onboarding-title text-body">Test</h4>
            <div class="onboarding-info">
            In this example you can see a form where you can request some additional information
            from the customer when they land on the app page.
            </div>
            <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="roleEx3" class="form-label">Discount</label>
                    <select class="form-select" tabindex="0" id="roleEx3">
                    <option>Senior Citizen - 20%</option>
                    <option>Business Owner</option>
                    <option>Other</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer border-0">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-label-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
            Close
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock modal_scripts %}
```

**mymainfile.html**    admin/mymainfile.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %} {% block content %} {% load staticfiles %}

 <html> ...some code of html here..... </html>


{% block modal_scripts %} {% csrf_token %} {% endblock modal_scripts %}


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include) certain html snippets.

templates/modal.html:

```html
<div class="modal-onboarding modal fade animate__animated" id="onboardImageModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content text-center">

[...]

    {{ custom_variable }}

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

templates/example1.html

```html
<h1>Hello world</h1>
{% include "modal.html" %}
```

If you want to pass variables to the template you can do this.

templates/example2.html

```html
<h1>Goodbye World</h1>
{% include "modal.html" with custom_variable=12 %}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to pass some value like parameter into modal, I've been thinking to resize the modal, hide some button, change text etc. it depends of the transaction

Comment: I edited my response. The answer could've been found also in the documentation exactly where I linked it.

Comment: I have one more question, is there any way to pass all the html design to modal? I mean just like this `{% include "modal.html" with htmldesign="<div class="" so on and so on>" %}`

Comment: Your options with django's templating system: `include`, `extend` and direct inserting of variables. Maybe the latter is what you're looking for.

Comment: what do you mean latter?

Comment: The latter is an english noun. It refers to the last thing someone mentioned. In the example "Of chicken, fish, and meat, I like the latter best." the expression "the latter" refers to "meat". In my case I wanted to say: You can write all your styling of html and divs and then insert normal variables. You can read about it in the django [Tutorial 03](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial03/#use-the-template-system)